# Binding the timeupdate event with a div

Tags: jquery, html, events, binding

Trying to get a div with the id #banner to display when a video plays for 3 seconds using the timeupdate event. I then want it to fade out once the video has played for 6 seconds. This is my code thus far, but I can't get it to work..

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="banner">Win!</div>
<div id="container">
    <header>    
        <h1>Backin' Up</h1>
    </header>
<section>
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video id="video2" controls>
        <source src="videos/wotebackinupsong.mp4">
        <source src="videos/wotebackinupsong.ogv">
    </video>
</div>
```

etc...

jQuery:

```
$('#video2').bind('timeudpate', function() {
var playTime = Math.round( $(this).get(0).currentTime );
    if(playTime == 3) {
        $('#banner').fadeIn(200);
    }
    if(playTime == 6) {
        $('#banner').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: where is your video ?

Comment: I added in the video code

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in your code (“uppate”):

```
$('#video2').bind('timeudpate', function() {
```

It should be ok after changing to the following:

```
$('#video2').bind('timeupdate', function() {
```